# Angular Highcharts Reading from multi objects elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a question about highcharts(bar chart).

**html**

```
<div id="SchoolPurchasedResource" style="width:100%; height:400px;">
</div>
```

**High charts**

This is the data format that I want
data: [
['Youtube', 23.7],['Discovery', 16.1]]

But what I got from database are

```
[{"act_id":418,"act_title":" Discovery","act_type":1,"act_info":"discovery.com","session_seconds":null,"no_students":null},{"act_id":25626,"act_title":"www.youtube.com","act_type":1,"act_info":"www.youtube.com","session_seconds":null,"no_students":null}]
```

I only need act_title and session_seconds to be displayed in my graph so how should I pass required data to "data"? P.S I don't want to ask database guy for another procedure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help you

```
var data = [{"act_id":418,"act_title":" Discovery","act_type":1,"act_info":"discovery.com","session_seconds":null,"no_students":null},{"act_id":25626,"act_title":"www.youtube.com","act_type":1,"act_info":"www.youtube.com","session_seconds":null,"no_students":null}]
var requiredData = data.map(function(item){
  return [item.act_title, item.act_type];
})
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Love your answer, it helps me a lot! Thanks !